# How to create pagination in express with MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, pagination

I want to use pagination in express with MySQL database. I have read many more posts for use pagination in express but did not find any post to solve my problem. I have found the post which use in pagination in express with monogodb but I want with MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

Use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` while querying your data.

For example, to get the first 30 data, you use

```
SELECT * FROM DATA LIMIT 30;
```

And to get the second page, use

```
SELECT * FROM DATA LIMIT 30 OFFSET 30;
```

In your Express app, make page as one of the params you process in the API logic. That simple.